# Define types for constant list to get auto complete

Tags: typescript

I have a JS library that I want to export `Constants` so that people using vscode or typescript can get auto complete for specific constants options.

I've tried exporting a Constant in `index.d.ts` with an interface and different option types, but no luck. How can I achieve this?

`index.d.ts`

```
type ColorOption =
  | "blue"
  | "green"
  | "red"
  | "white"
  | "gray";

interface Constant {
  Colors: ColorOption;
  Fonts: ...;
  Icons: ...;
  Spacing: ...;

}

export default Constant
```

Ideally the autocomplete will be for example `Constants.Colors.red` or `Constants.Fonts.xlarge`

EDIT:

adding `export type` only works if I used it in a prop like `<Component type="red" />` but enum seems to works when using `Constants.Colors.red`. Is there a way for both to work?

Comment: You're trying to make it so if the user types `Colors.` they get the autocomplete options `blue`, `green`, etc.? Maybe you want an [enum](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need to do [is](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/history/index.d.ts):

```
export type ColorOption =
  | "blue"
  | "green"
  | "red"
  | "white"
  | "gray";

export interface Constant {
  Colors: ColorOption;
  Fonts: ...;
  Icons: ...;
  Spacing: ...;

}
```